# ZFS: how to receive into root of pool?

Tags: zfs

It seems like it would be an easy question, but I've been looking around for several days and can't figure out a way to do this.

Part of the problem with finding an answer seems to be that most articles on google are referencing the bootable pool.

I'm trying to restore a snapshot like this:

```
zfs send -R backupset/storage07@repl-marker-20150210 | zfs receive -Fev storage07
```

Unfortunetly, it always tries to restore the dataset as a child of storage07, as in storage07/storage07.

I want to restore the snapshot into the root of the pool, not a sub dataset inside the pool.

I thought that the `-e -d` modifiers were supposed to switch between path vs no path, but they seem to yield the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zfs rename`, after you rollback the dataset to the received snapshot (and you will have to do it probably, for example when restoring to an empty or already used pool/dataset).

Comment: The dataset I'm restoring to is a new dataset

Comment: How would I write this snapshot to the root of a different pool?

Comment: Write it to the same dataset as original one, then rename.

Comment: so for example you are saying that i could do something like this? zfs rename tank/home/maybee tank

Comment: Yup. Just be sure you won't lose anything, like the originat content of the `tank`.